# Is this Hadith Authentic? I cant find a reference anywhere

Tags: hadith

> Al-Bukhaari (4343) and Muslim (3032) narrated that Ibn ‘Umar (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: I heard ‘Umar (may Allaah be pleased with him) say from the minbar of the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him): “O people, the prohibition of khamr was revealed when khamr was made from five things: grapes, dates, honey, wheat and barley. Khamr is whatever befogs the mind.”

I cant seem to find a reference.

Comment: You're funny you post a hadith with two references (al-Bukhari 4343) and (Muslim 3032) and say you can't find a reference? Of course you may find it referenced otherwise as there's no standard in this but al-Bukhari and Muslim clearly refers to the two sahih books. The rest is a matter of simple search!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a missed homework question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these are authentic hadith from Bukhari and Muslim.

Read the [Bukhari hadith](https://sunnah.com/urn/179490) and the similar [Muslim hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim/56/37).

Hope this helps.